# What is the meaning of「って」here?

Tags: grammar, particle-って

I have hard time following the dialogue by a single character from a certain manga.

> 貴方は安達垣愛姫を選ぶ
>
> でも、それは復讐のため
>
> 恋じゃない
>
> でしたら、わたくしと恋をしたって
>
> 浮気にはなりませんでしょう?

How can I understand the fourth and fifth sentence? Does the「って」in the fourth sentence mean "if"? Is it something among the lines of

> If that's case, if you fall in love with me, then it will not become affair?

Perhaps this「って」is a colloquial topic marker.

> If that's case, speaking of falling in love with me, it will not become affair?

I'm not sure what is the correct meaning of「って」in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second definition of 「たって」 [here 1](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF&source=hp&ei=481dYOzGKoSSlwTOt6-wCw&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYF3b8znR5qD7p_7iVwsjKIDD8ynCNV0F&oq=%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAQQCjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjoOCC4QsQMQxwEQowIQkwI6CAgAELEDEIMBOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoOCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQowI6BQgAELEDOgQIABAEOgIIADoICAAQBBAKECo6BggAEAQQHlCGFFiMKWD8K2gCcAB4AIABgAOIAY0IkgEHNy4xLjAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXqwAQA&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwisxP629c3vAhUEyYUKHc7bC7YQ4dUDCAk&uact=5) (I hope it shows up properly) is 「たとしても。ても。」 Basically, たって is a slightly more colloquial way to say 'even if'. (I believe it's derived from 「～たとて」.) It's usually made with the past tense plus 「～って」, but with い adjectives it goes after the 連用形, as in 「赤くたって」.

'In that case, even if you fell in love with me, it wouldn't be cheating, would it?'

Comment: You could also remember how to make the form like this: take the て-form of whatever you're trying to attach たって to and just replace the て (で) with たって (だって). This also works well with i-adjectives and だ.

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on the answer from Angelos:「って」is the colloquial way to express「として」, you could also use 「ても」instead of「たって」, which is the is shorter version of「としても」.

でしたら、わたくしと恋をした**って**

- "That's why, **even if** you make love to me,"

浮気にはなりませんでしょう?

- "it won't be cheating, right?"